# Can i Know how Eclipse automatically compiles Java code?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 2018-12 with JDK 11.

If I use .class files automatically built by Eclipse to build my jar file, things works fine (the goal is an aar file, for a very simple web service).

But if I use an Ant build, my jar isn't working.

To be clearer: I created a simple Java project, with a package named ws and Serv.java in it;  Eclipse automatically created a directory named modules.hello.jigsaw with ws/Serv.class inside.

If I use this class file (and services.xml, of course) to make Serv.jar, all is good.

But if I compile with an Ant build, generating my Serv.class, the aar file is unloadable, it isn't correct.

Probably I'm not using the right javac command.

So, my real question is: is there any way to know "how" Eclipse compiles ?
 which options it uses when making a javac command ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possibly, you're right.

Comment: In a launch (Run/Debug) configuration there is a _Show Command Line_ button to get the `java` command whose arguments are not the same but similar to the `javac` command. Maybe you can use that as a starting point since there is no such button for `javac`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has implemented its own compiler called as ECJ ([Eclipse Java Compiler](http://blog.deepakazad.com/2010/05/ecj-eclipse-java-compiler.html))

Comment: Ok, thank you all. So I have to understand ECJ and then try to "translate" into javac commands

Comment: @VirgilioRavagli You shouldn't need to understand ECJ, it doesn't do anything particularly special. Most likely there is something wrong with your ant build.xml.

Comment: The same code and the same ant build work fine if I add source and target =1.8 in the <javac> tag. I guess it's related to modularity, even if I'm not using modules